# Information about reputation requirement for creating rooms chat FAQ

Tags: feature-request, chat

I think that there is lack of important information in chat [FAQ](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/faq) about reputation requirement for creating rooms.

There is information about reputation requirement for writing and I spend lot of time to realise that there is another requirement for creating rooms at all.

I found it on [privileges page](https://stackoverflow.com/help/privileges), but I looked there only after suggestion from other people.

Comment: Well... creating rooms _is_ a privilege. At most I think there should be something like "Some actions require privileges to complete. See: <link to privileges>"

Comment: It would be appropriate implementation i think

Comment: The last thing we need is more duplication of information. Links to the correct information would be more appropriate so that if the privilege level is changed in the future, that information doesn't have to be changed in multiple places.

Comment: Yes, i meant that i agree with you, that you suggested good implementation of my request.

Comment: Ahhh ok, I was confused. Carry on.

Comment: Should i add this to my question to make it more specific? I really dont know yet how questions like that handling here. Should question describe the  specific changes i suppose or just be a theme to discuss?

Comment: If you want to, go ahead, either is fine